# Smart Indexing with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an 4 dimensional array (named colors) which assigns a color (ie 3 values R, G, B) to each 3d point (x, y, z) -> (r, g, b) 
I have another 2 dimensional array (named visible) which tells me which z pane I can see when I look down on it (x, y)->z
I want to create 3 dimensional array (view) which tells me what I see. (x, y) -> (r, g, b)

How can I do that with numpy smart indexing?

I tried

```
colors=np.array([
  [
  [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]],

  [
  [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]],
  [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]])

visible=np.array(
  [[0, 1],
   [1, 0]])

view=colors[:, :,visible[:, :]]

expected=np.array(
[[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]],
 [[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]]])
```

But that gives me 5 dimensional array.

Comment: Could you explain a little better what you are trying to achieve, is not clear why `0` becomes `[0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: Isn't the last element of your `expected` erroneous?

Comment: @John Zwick: You were right. I corrected expected in the question

Comment: @ RaySteam: Because colors[0, 0, visible[0, 0]] is [0, 0, 0]

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sorry about that, Zwick is a not so uncommon  German name (there is even a measurement instrument company with that name ) (and I am German).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
x = np.array([[0,1],[0,1]])
y = np.array([[0,0],[1,1]])
colors[(visible, y, x)]
```

It gives:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1]]])
```

`x` and `y` select which pixels you want, while `visible` is your `z` plane selector.  They can actually be 1D and they will broadcast to fill the other dimension.  You can construct arbitrary-size `x` and `y` like this:

```
x = np.arange(colors.shape[2])
y = np.arange(colors.shape[1]).reshape(-1,1) # transpose
```

Comment: How do you get x and y? (My real problem is of course from arrays much bigger than 2, 2, 2, 3 and 2,2)

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck: I've added to my answer showing how to generalize it.  Hopefully I got the subscripts/dimensions correct, but I'm sure you'll get the idea.

Comment: Should be `x = np.arange(2).reshape(-1, 1)` and `y = np.arange(2).reshape(1, -1)`. Also, probably `visible[x, y]` is more correct

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was quite interesting and challenging.

[Numpy's advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) works a bit other like you tried to use it intuitively.

There are more options to achieve what you want:

**1.** You can use advanced indexing as follows using with a bit help of [numpy.indices()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html):

```
import numpy as np

colors=np.array([
  [
  [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]],

  [
  [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]],
  [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]])


visible = np.array(
  [[0, 1],
   [1, 0]])

x_ind, y_ind = np.indices(visible.shape)

view = colors[visible, x_ind, y_ind]

print(view)
```

**Out:**

```
[[[0 0 0]
  [1 1 0]]

 [[0 1 1]
  [0 0 1]]]
```

**2.** Alternatively you can use [numpy.choose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html#numpy.choose) which is very intuitive way in this case:

```
import numpy as np

colors=np.array([
  [
  [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]],

  [
  [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]],
  [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]])

visible = np.array(
  [[0, 1],
   [1, 0]])

visible = visible.reshape(2,2,1)

view = np.choose(visible, colors)

print(view)
```

**Out:**

```
[[[0 0 0]
  [1 1 0]]

 [[0 1 1]
  [0 0 1]]]
```